# Errors related to 'for' loop in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming and have been trying to learn android programming using [this](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/twitter/8/listview-getView-example) tutorial.

I am executing the below mentioned code and have been getting the errors below. Ever after a lot of trying I have not been able to solve them:

```
package com.example.sony.myapplication.twitter;

import com.example.sony.myapplication.TweetAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tweet{
    List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

    for(int i = 0; i <20; i++ ) {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
        tweet.setTitle("A nice header for Tweet # " +i);
        tweet.setBody("Some random body text for the tweet # " +i);
        tweets.add(tweet);
        TweetAdapter tweetItemArrayAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this, new String[10]);
    }
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setBody(String body) {
    this.body = body;
}
```

Errors:

```
1.Error:(17, 5) error: illegal start of type
2.Error:(17, 14) error: ')' expected
3.Error:(17, 17) error: illegal start of type
4.Error:(17, 18) error: <identifier> expected
5.Error:(17, 19) error: ';' expected
6.Error:(17, 23) error: <identifier> expected
7.Error:(17, 25) error: illegal start of type
8.Error:(17, 28) error: '(' expected
9.Error:(28, 12) error: class, interface, or enum expected
10.Error:(30, 5) error: class, interface, or enum expected
11.Error:(32, 12) error: class, interface, or enum expected
12.Error:(34, 5) error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Errors 1 to 8 are related to the `for` loop.

Errors 9 and 10 are related to the `setTitle` function.

Errors 11 and 12 are related to `setBody` function.

In Android Studio the `for` loop is being shown as `Unexpected Token`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: thanks to Takendarkk for alerting me to my incorrect answer.
As stated by Takendarkk and BeingMIAkashs, the for loop must be in its own method.

```
public class Tweet {

    List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    String title;
    String body;

    public Tweet() {
        setTweets();
    }

    private void setTweets() {
        for(int i = 0; i <20; i++ ) {
            Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
            tweet.setTitle("A nice header for Tweet # " +i);
            tweet.setBody("Some random body text for the tweet # " +i);
            tweets.add(tweet);
        }
        TweetAdapter tweetItemArrayAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this, new String[10]);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

Also, the parameters you're passing onto your adapter, unless there's something going on in your adapter that I'm not aware of, will result in a list of 10 empty items. Are you sure you don't mean this:

```
TweetAdapter tweetItemArrayAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this, tweets);
```

Comment: You can't place a for loop in a class body. It must be in a method. Your code will not compile.

Comment: @Takendarkk Yikes! I probably shouldn't be hanging out here while I've got the flu ;). Updated my answer, hopefully didn't overlook something again. Thanks!

Comment: saved my time! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the for loop inside any of your method. You can not write the for loop outside the method.